# Show custom error message

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, formvalidation.io

I'm trying to show errors in form validation.
But these messages are always visible.

```
<form name="user-form" method="POST" action="{{route('registrationUser')}}">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
              Логин <input type="text" name="log" ng-model="mobile"   required pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*"><br>
               <span class="help-block" ng-show="errors.log[0]"><p>Только английский</p></span>
         </div>

          Пароль <input type="text" name="pass" ng-minlength="8" ng-pattern="regex" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{8,32}" ><br>
         <div ng-show="user-form.pass.$error.pattern">Name doesn't match pattern!</div>
         <button ng-click='SaveUser()' name="Регистрация">Регисрация</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: make it empty <div> and let the validation message to fill it

Comment: Whats this `Только английский`? ( Russian )  What do you mean always visible?  you could do `style="display:none;"` then use Javascript to show them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add another condition to ng-show

```
<div ng-show="user-form.pass.$error.pattern && buttonclicked">Name doesn't match pattern!</div>
```

and set that condition to true in your controller

```
$scope.SaveUser= function () {
    $scope.buttonclicked = true;
};
```

so error messages will be visible only when user clicks on submit button